# Camelot/Ghostscript path does not exist

Tags: python, ghostscript, python-camelot

I am new to Python coding and currently I am trying to use the Camelot library to read some tables off of a PDF file. I am using a Windows 11 computer with VSCode to write Python.
From my understanding, I need to also have Ghostscript and Tkinter installed as well for Camelot to work properly, however, when trying to test it, the code does not recognize the functions.

This is the code I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
import tkinter
import camelot

ghost_Path = find_library('gs')
# ghost_Path = "C:/Program Files/gs/gs10.01.1/bin/gsdll64.dll"               #The correct path

debug = True

if(debug):
    print("Debug Mode: On\n")
else:
    print("Debug Mode: Off\n")

if ghost_Path is not None:
    print("Ghost path is found at: ", ghost_Path)
else:
    print("Ghost PATH does not exist.\n")


data = camelot.read_pdf("foo.pdf")

print("Total Tables in PDF: ", data.n)
```

As I am new to Python, I don't know much about general debugging practices, but I have tried to reinstall everything making note of each path, and then manually adding them to my environmental variables in my system.
I thought this would have solved the issue or at least presented a potential solution, but when I used the find_library function to check if the path to Ghostscript existed at all, it didn't work.

Comment: I have the very same problem. Did you solve your problem?